# Errors in Paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to create a php page to set up a paypal payment but not sure how to go about it.

I've tried to get the basics working from this tutorial here: 
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

Here is the code (I have commented out the line of code that do not work):

I have the following problems.

1.) apicontext is an undefined variable in another file so I cannot see how its declared.  If there is a way to get around this without calling this variable that would be great.

2.) The redirect URLS I had to comment out because the getBaseUrl() is undefined (in another file)

2.) I get the following errors - there is more along the same lines:

```
( ! ) Warning: error_log(../PayPal.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /teaching/courses/co639/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalLoggingManager.php on line 116
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0017  238856  {main}( )   ../purchase_create.php:0
2   0.0135  408648  PayPal\Api\Payment->create( )   ../purchase_create.php:62
3   0.0136  409784  PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall( )   ../Payment.php:303
4   0.0140  427152  PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute( ) ../PayPalResourceModel.php:103
5   0.0144  446320  PayPal\Handler\RestHandler->handle( )   ../PayPalRestCall.php:71
6   0.0150  477024  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->getAccessToken( ) ../RestHandler.php:80
7   0.0154  480408  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->updateAccessToken( )  ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:164
8   0.0154  480712  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->generateAccessToken( )    ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:212
9   0.0154  481328  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->getToken( )   ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:267
10  0.0157  493288  PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute( )    ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:243
11  0.0157  493520  PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager->info( )   ../PayPalHttpConnection.php:82
12  0.0157  493968  PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager->log( )    ../PayPalLoggingManager.php:148
13  0.0158  494512  error_log ( )   ../PayPalLoggingManager.php:116

( ! ) Warning: error_log(../PayPal.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /teaching/courses/co639/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalLoggingManager.php on line 116
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0017  238856  {main}( )   ../purchase_create.php:0
2   0.0135  408648  PayPal\Api\Payment->create( )   ../purchase_create.php:62
3   0.0136  409784  PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall( )   ../Payment.php:303
4   0.0140  427152  PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute( ) ../PayPalResourceModel.php:103
5   0.0144  446320  PayPal\Handler\RestHandler->handle( )   ../PayPalRestCall.php:71
6   0.0150  477024  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->getAccessToken( ) ../RestHandler.php:80
7   0.0154  480408  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->updateAccessToken( )  ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:164
8   0.0154  480712  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->generateAccessToken( )    ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:212
9   0.0154  481328  PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->getToken( )   ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:267
10  0.0157  493288  PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute( )    ../OAuthTokenCredential.php:243
11  1.2623  502104  PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager->info( )   ../PayPalHttpConnection.php:157
12  1.2623  502248  PayPal\Core\PayPalLoggingManager->log( )    ../PayPalLoggingManager.php:148
13  1.2623  502496  error_log ( )
```

Struggling to get this simple example to work for me any help getting the beasics to work would be great.

Comment: This means that it can't write to the PayPal.log so create that file and put write permissions on it.

Answer (score -1):

[PayPal-PHP-SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/) has created [wiki documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki) that helps you setup your machine to use PayPal SDK.

You can follow the instructions to make your first call here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call

Once you follow all the steps provided, you should be able to get started really easily. Let me know if that helps. We have [PayPal PHP SDK](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/) Page setup for all useful information you may need.